# Cancel a RestSharp Request

Tags: windows-phone-7, restsharp

I'm making a wp7 app that uses RestSharp to download some data. I noticed the application guidelines require that I provide a ui element that allows the user to cancel a data transfer. Is it possible to cancel an ExecuteAsync request with rest sharp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ExecuteAsync()` returns an `RestRequestAsyncHandle` which has an `Abort()` method you can call to kill the request.